# Como exibir uma imagem com sessão em PHP

Tags: php

O que eu posso fazer para exibir uma imagem (apenas o endereço está gravado) que está gravado no banco usando as sessões?

Answer (score 1):

Vinicius, como você não deu detalhe algum do que você tem de código, estou te dando um exemplo muito genérico de como poderia ser feito, mas, isso é longe do ideal a ser feito, é só uma noção de como poderia ser.

```
<?php
$endImagem = funcaoSelectImagem(); // Retorna o campo com o endereço completo da imagem.
if ($endImagem != NULL) {
   ?>
   <img src="<?php print($endImagem) ?>" width="200" height="200">
   <?php
} else {
   print("Imagem não existe.");
}
?>
```

Comment: Perdão por não colocar o código, obrigado mesmo assim Luis